# Реализация удаления неактивных пользователей postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Логика такая. Когда пользователь регистрируется, ему надо подтвердить свою почту, но бывают же случаи когда уже например сделал опечатку или добавил лишний символ, я планирую удалять такие пользователей через 15 дней.

Пример таблицы

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
CREATE TABLE users(
    user_id                             SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    user_name                           VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
    user_email                          VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
    user_password                       VARCHAR(220) NOT NULL,
    ...
    confirmed_email                     BOOLEAN
);
```

Столбец `confirmed_email` отвечает за то, подтвердил ли пользователь свою почты или нет. Как удалять таких пользователей я знаю.

Вопрос: как отсчитать 15 дней и если в течении этого времени он не подтвердил свою почты удалить этого пользователя с базы данных?

Comment: 1. сохраниить дату регистрации. 2. Запустить проверку(например раз в день). Если прошло больше 15 дней, удалить

Comment: это надо написать функцию в postgresql?

Comment: это зависит от того, что и как вы делаете. По идее достаточно написать запрос, вопрос только в том, что его будет вызывать. Хранимый код в постгресс или что-то снаружи(да хоть ручками самому запускать)

Comment: Зачем функция? тем более зачем руками? Используйте [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron). А запрос на удаление "старых записей" - вообще тривиальный (см. самый первый пример).

Comment: Собственно я никогда не работал с постгресс, наверное там есть какой нибудь планировщик

Comment: @Viktorov *я никогда не работал с постгресс* Та же фигня. Но кому это мешает? *наверное там есть какой нибудь планировщик* Искаропки - нет. Тот, что предложен выше, регается как плагин - и тогда работает как родной.

Comment: @Akina ну гуглить за автора, какой есть планировщик для постгресса мне откровенно говоря лениво

Comment: @MegaRoks планировщик на самом деле выбирайте какой больше по душе. А про дату создания никаких функций не надо. добавляете колонку timestamp и пишите в нее при создании пользователя текущую дату, которую можно получить прямо в постгресе CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Ну и удаление получается элементарное, `where ... and date_create < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '15 day'`

Comment: @Mike спасибо за ответ, я так и сделаю